# 404 error servlet jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I am currently working on a simple web App project with eclipse.

I use centos server and apache-tomcat-7.0.47.

I have an **index.jsp** file:

```
<form action="MyServlet">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

My servlet file **MyServlet.java** :

```
package com.srk.pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
  * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
*/
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
      * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public MyServlet() {
       super();
    }

   /**
       * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello Everybody..");
   }

   /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

and my **web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Example1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The problem I have is:

I run the web app from eclipse and everything is ok.

```
 http://localhost:8080/Example1/index.jsp
```

and

```
 http://localhost:8080/Example1/MyServlet?
```

but when i try accessing it from my centos server i get a

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Example1/WebContent/MyServlet
```

type Status report

```
message /Example1/WebContent/MyServlet
```

description The requested resource is not available.

Can anyone help me??

The links i use:

```
.....:8080/Example1/WebContent/index.jsp
```

and

```
....:8080/Example1/WebContent/MyServlet?
```

also

[image: Package explorer]

Comment: Whats your centos version ? and Does your centos server started? or have you checked it ?

Comment: version 6.4 and its started i used /sbin/service https restart command

Comment: Whats the port number for your centos server?

Comment: this is the link to the web app http://83.212.98.109:8080/Example1/WebContent/index.jsp

Comment: In your `<form action` try this `./MyServlet`

Comment: no its not working.It shows the same error

Comment: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>./MyServlet" try this

Comment: the problem is your application doesnt find the right path for your servlet . its still inside the webcontent directory

Comment: type Status report

message /Example1./MyServlet

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: yes this is what i think too..It can't find the right path i am trying 2 days now to fix it and nothing

Comment: sry remove the **dot** here . try this `"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyServlet"` have to work .. paste this inside form action

Comment: i am thinking the problem might be in apache.i believe the code is correct

Comment: I removed the dot but nothing changed

Comment: Yeah i guess the same . servlet might have not been instantiated. Check whether you have the class file here `build/classes`

Comment: the path /Example1/build is empty
the path /Example1/src/.… contains the MyServlet.java
the path /Example1/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes contains the path to MyServlet.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to access

```
/Example1/WebContent/MyServlet
```

?

Everything in the `WebContent` directory in your project will end up being at the root of the generated `war` file. Everything not in `WEB-INF` will be accessible, so you can do

```
/Example1/index.jsp
```

Otherwise, you have to go through a `Servlet`. You don't have a url mapping that matches

```
/Example1/WebContent/MyServlet
```

and that therefore gives you a 404.

You do have a url mapping for

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can access that at

```
/Example1/MyServlet
```

Note that submitting this form in a browser

```
<form action="MyServlet">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

depends on your current URL. If you had made your previous request to

```
/Example1/index.jsp
```

then submitting the form will send the request to

```
/Example1/MyServlet
```

If you were on

```
/Example1/some/random/path
```

then submitting will send the request to

```
/Example1/some/random/MyServlet
```

If you want to make your request always go to the same URL, you should make your path absolute

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!i run the .jsp with action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet">
but again nothing happened.I have 404 error again but now the message is :message /Example1/MyServlet
I can't understand why it doesn't work..the servlet now is on the right path

Comment: @tasos.kou Adding a log statement (system.out.print) in your `Servlet`'s constructor then add `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to your `<servlet>` element. When you start the Servlet container, check if the log statement is printed.

Comment: I added the `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to the servlet and i put a `System.out.println("hello, world");` under `super();` in MyServlet.

Eclipse printed out hello,world in the console..nothing happened in my server

Comment: @tasos.kou You will have to show us how you deploy it on centos server.

Comment: I hope i understand what you want me to show you.I made the changes you told me in eclipse then i passed the folder (Example1) via FileZilla on my server.this is the link (http://83.212.98.109:8080/Example1/WebContent/index.jsp) which leads to (http://83.212.98.109:8080/Example1/MyServlet) error 404

Comment: @tasos It's possible you're just deploying it wrong. With eclipse, select your project and export it to a `.war` file. Take that file and put it in your server's `tomcat-installation/webapps` directory, then restart tomcat.

Comment: Yesssss!!!Finally it worked!!many many thanks!!So when i have more than 1 .jsp the .war file will run the index.jsp one??right?

Comment: @tasos.kou It has nothing to do with how many JSPs you have. The `.war` file contains your whole web application, including servlets and JSPs.

Comment: @tasos.kou Also, consider upvoting/accepting answers if they helped. That's how stackoverflow goes 'round.

Comment: I was trying to up vote but i can't do it. Unfortunately in need 15 Reputation

Comment: @tasos.kou Don't worry about that. If you have any other questions, don't hesitate.